# batch File: Search for a file from PC list

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to create bat file;
I have a list of PC's in a txt file
1- Ping and log it to txt file
2- Search for a specific file:
if exists echo to txt file
if not exist echo to text file.

The ping part is fine and working but I am having an issue with checking on the file if it exists or not.
here is what I am working with:
Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

@ECHO off

2- SETLOCAL=ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

3- SET /a count=0

::Deletes Existing Results File

IF exist "FileSearch.txt" DEL "FileSearch.txt"

::Inserts a Date

ECHO %date% >>FileSearch.txt

ECHO Start Measure %Time% >>FileSearch.txt

::Start Bat

:: Reads from a Txt File List

for /F %%i in (TestList.txt) do (

set /a count+=1

::Check if the PC Online

ping %%i -n 1

IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1  ( ECHO %%i:    Register Online.>>FileSearch.txt ) ELSE  ( ECHO %%i:    PC Offline.>>FileSearch.txt)
)

:: all above is working fine

::Check if Exists

if not exist (\%%i\c$"\Program Files\Soft\Installer\debug.txt") ( ECHO %%i:        file found.>>FileSearch.txt

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to create bat file; I have a list of PC's in a txt file 1- Ping and log it to txt file 2- Search for a specific file: if exists echo to txt file if not exist echo to text file.
I got it resolved.